# Hyphen usage with with multiple compound adjectives separated by or/and

Tags: adjectives, hyphens, compounds

I have the following question. I have a structure like this:

> dark-looking or sinister-looking

Can I write it like this:

> dark- or sinister-looking

Comment: This question has previously been asked on the EL&U site [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/566456/chocolate-and-vanilla-flavored-cookies-using-a-hyphenated-compound-adjectiv). It did not recieve any answers and commenters indicated that they had not seen this before, as I haven't. Nonetheless this is a good question. My own inclination would be to write it as ***...dar, or sinister-looking***. But I'm certainly open to other views.

Comment: I have seen this usage before and do use it myself, although I agree that it is not widespread and maybe not known by most people.  My guess is that it was imported from another language like German that might do this regularly.

Comment: I think it is usage to be recommended because it distinguishes two meanings: a person with a dark complexion who is sinister looking and a person who had a demeanor that is dark and sinister.

Comment: Nothing terribly unusual about suspended hyphens [APA Style](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2016/10/hyphenation-station-repeated-hyphens-in-a-phrase.html)

Comment: Don't do this. First, dark-looking and sinister-looking are complicated ways of saying that something appears sinister. To add -looking to them is almost always unnecessary. Second, whenever you encounter this structure, it's a huge neon sign that you're better off rewriting your sentence.

Comment: Again, no. If someone has a dark complexion, then describe their skin tone. You don't use "dark-looking" because that's not specific. Good writing is specific, and it avoids unnecessarily complex sentence structures. You will find that advice taught by almost every class on how to write. Please go do your own research if you don't buy it.

Comment: What is it you're trying to say?  Why use **or** instead of **and**?  What's wrong with *looking dark and/or sinister*.  All the necessary words are there, the meaning remains the same, and there is no need for obtuse hyphen constructions.  To be honest, if I saw that dangling hyphen I would probably stop reading what you'd written right there, regardless of what any style books say.  Your sentence looks more like an equation than a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

No, you could not hyphenate the entire sentence as you suggested.

Hyphens are used to make compound nouns or compound adjectives when there would otherwise be some doubt over which word was being modified. For example, if you omitted the hyphen from the expression "an angry-looking dog", a person might ask "what's a *looking-dog*"? There is no such confusion in your example.

You would not normally use a hyphen to join a conjunction, especially not "or", as the word itself is there to connect otherwise separate parts of speech. You do not, therefore, need to connect them further with hyphens.

The other problem I have with your suggestion is that 'dark' and 'sinister' do not have exactly the same meaning anyway, so why are you using "or" to present the two as if something is one or the other? Do you not mean that something is "dark **and** sinister-looking"?

> Dark and sinister-looking.

Whether something is 'sinister' or not may be a matter of opinion. Whether something is 'dark' is more a matter of fact. I think you mean to say that something *is* dark, but *looks* sinister, in which case there is no real need to say "dark-looking".

Comment: This is not about the specific example. This is about general use. For example: 
"I couldn't decide if he was good- or bad-looking." Omitting the hyphen there would change the meaning of the whole sentence. Your answer was not very helpful.

Comment: @GeTo My answer isn't specific to the example you gave. I explained that we would not use a hyphen to join the word "or" to any word, because "or" is there to join two options. So the example you give in your comment would be wrong, too. Further, I would say "I couldn't decide if he was good-looking or not", as "bad-looking" is not really idiomatic in the context.

Comment: I'm going to use the guidance by the American Psychological Association. [Here](https://apastyle.apa.org/learn/faqs/when-use-hyphen)

Comment: @GeTo That's a 'style guide'. that means it is the guidance for one particular organisation to ensure that all their publications are consistent with their use of language. If you're writing for American Psychologists then they'll be pleased with it.

Comment: @GeTo - Will you continue to use the guidance provided by the American Psychological Association for all future questions about writing style?  If so, I don't think we can be much more use to you.  There is no purpose in our providing answers if you've already made up your mind.

Answer (score 0):

APA guidelines say:

> When two or more compound modifiers have a common base, this base is sometimes omitted in all except the last modifier, but the hyphens are retained.

The examples they give are “Long- and short-term memory” and “2-, 3-, and 10-min trials.” It appears that using this hyphenated form is usually only applicable to situations in which the hyphenated adjectives *both* apply to whatever is being modified. It’s also worth noting that this shouldn’t be applied to redundant adjectives; the examples here use the structure to apply *different* adjectives to the same object.

Second, “-looking” is only used when you must clarify that the adjective applies to a specific speaker’s personal perspective, and not necessarily to reality. For example, you may say “the mean-looking man” to show that, although you’re not sure that the man actually is a mean person, it appears that way to you. On the other hand, something like “the blond-looking man” would not make sense, because “blond” itself isn’t really subjective. It also doesn’t apply to adjectives that are, by nature, purely subjective. You would not say “an ugly-looking man,” you would just say “an ugly man.”

Finally, there are usually other ways to write the same meaning that are less confusing. This compounded hyphen form seems to apply mostly to scientific or non-fiction situations in which writing for conciseness and meaning is more important than how the writing “flows.”